# What is wrong with this ternary operator?

Tags: python

```
for i in str1:
    (newstr += chr(ord(i)+2)) if i.isalpha() else (newstr += i)
```

It seems to be grieving about the += operator. I know both my variables are strings though, so I don't understand why it would not just concatenate them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for i in str1:
    newstr += (chr(ord(i)+2) if i.isalpha() else i)
```

**Edit**:

From [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
expression             ::=  conditional_expression | lambda_expr
```

And as pointed by @flornquake, the assignment `var += value` is a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator `a if cond else b` works with expressions, but `newstr += chr(ord(i)+2)` is a statement.

You need to use the if-statement in this case:

```
for i in str1:
    if i.isalpha():
        newstr += chr(ord(i)+2)
    else:
        newstr += i
```

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator in Python expects expressions (like `newstr + i`) but you try to use a statement (`newstr += i` is equivalent to `newstr = newstr + i`).

One way to correct your code would be:

```
newstr = ''
for i in str1:
  newstr += chr(ord(i)+2) if i.isalpha() else i
```

You should not concatenate strings in this way, though.

A better approach would be:

```
newstr = ''.join(chr(ord(c)+2) for c in str1 if c.isalpha() else c)
```

Still another way (only works with ASCII characters!):

```
import string
fro = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
to = 'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX[\\'
t = string.maketrans(fro, to)
newstr = str1.translate(t)
```